# How can I verify my PayPal account without giving them direct access to my bank account?

Tags: security, paypal

Most sites where you can buy products with PayPal require your account to be verified. It appears that the only way to verify your account is by associating it with your bank account. I prefer not to give companies direct access to my bank account, since if there is an error on their end, a security breach, etc. I could be out a lot of money with no warning. I would like to associate it with a credit card instead, where the money won't be taken out of my account until I pay my monthly credit card bill. This gives me the ability to dispute claims through the credit card company, which is much more likely to succeed.

Is there any way to have a verified address using a credit card instead of direct access to my bank account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have verified mine with just a credit card by following the ["Add a credit card" option](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-credit-card-new-clickthru&flag_from_account_summary=1&nav=0.6.2) - just gone in and checked it now. The process involves PayPal charging a nominal small fee to the card, then you enter the code that will appear on your statement.

They still would prefer me to add a bank account to the details page (they offer to lift receiving limits if I do this) but my account is verified purely from the credit card validation.

(Caveat - I am in the UK. Rules may be different)

Comment: CC validation is norm, even in India where Paypal is very much hostile.

Comment: I finally got this to work after adding a temporary address (I'm living away from "home" at college right now) to my credit card. It was a bit of a pain, but finally worked.